# How to do di-directional syncing between a date input field and a number input field?

Tags: vuejs2, vuetify.js

I am attempting to create a "birthday" component in Vue.js.  I have 2 `v-text-field` components, one that has a type="date" and another that has a type="number".

The idea is that the user will either enter a birth date or their age.  If they enter their age, it will change what's in the date input and vice versa.

Everything works great except when I change the age input.  Instead of updating the date input value, it just reverts it to `mm/dd/yyyy`.

I created a codepen [here](https://codepen.io/jasonwilczak/pen/KKvqLRO?editors=101)

I can't figure out why it's not working as the underlaying data property is correct (i added a derived text area to show that the properties are updating correctly that you can see in the example below the "date of birth" input.

Comment: Your problem is about difference between what format does **age calculation** and **date calculation** use. second one produces **YYYY-MM-DD** while first one produces **MM/DD/YYYY**. Use `this.birthDate = newBirthDate.toISOString().substring(0, 10)` instead of yours in age calculation, or whatever is more appropriate.
`

Comment: omg, thank you! post the answer and I'll accept :)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is about difference between what format does **age calculation** and **date calculation** use. second one produces **YYYY-MM-DD** while first one produces **MM/DD/YYYY**.
Try this

```
this.birthDate = newBirthDate.toISOString().substring(0, 10)
```

instead of yours in age calculation, or whatever is more appropriate.